# MySQL Add missing Months in resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add missing months in this result set.

Where month is missing, add it with the value 0 for **Quantita**.

```
SELECT MONTH(Data) AS Mese,Count(*) AS Quantita 
FROM prenotazioni 
WHERE Cancellata IS NULL 
AND FKCampo = 1 
AND YEAR(Data) = YEAR(CURDATE()) -1 
GROUP BY Mese 
ORDER BY Mese ASC 


+------+----------+
| Mese | Quantita |
+------+----------+
| 4    | 123      |
+------+----------+
| 5    | 100      |
+------+----------+
| 7    | 377      |
+------+----------+
| 9    | 54       |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is messy and I am sure there has to be a cleaner way...

So, first I create a table with all the months:

```
CREATE TABLE all_months (
 month_num INT
);

INSERT INTO all_months VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
```

Then I join your query with this table (in my case on the right) and use a case-when to decide if there is a count or not:

```
SELECT 
  all_months.month_num, 
  CASE 
    WHEN tmp.Quantita is NULL THEN 0 
    ELSE tmp.Quantita 
  END as Quantita
FROM (
  SELECT MONTH(Data) AS Mese,Count(*) AS Quantita 
  FROM prenotazioni 
  WHERE Cancellata IS NULL 
  AND FKCampo = 1 
  AND YEAR(Data) = YEAR(CURDATE()) -1 
  GROUP BY Mese 
 ) as tmp
RIGHT JOIN all_months on all_months.month_num=tmp.Mese
ORDER BY all_months.month_num ASC
```

Your query is now in `tmp` and ordering is happening after that. The result is:

```
month_num   Quantita
1           1
2           2
3           0
4           0
5           0
6           0
7           0
8           3
9           1
10          0
11          1
12          1
```

Demo: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2df50bb9655a10cca7a56aa189ec7dbd)

Answer (score 1):

A solution that does not require creating a new table.

```
SELECT 
  `months`.`number`, 
  CASE 
    WHEN tmp.Quantita IS NULL THEN 0 
    ELSE tmp.Quantita 
  END AS Quantita
FROM (
  SELECT MONTH(Data) AS Mese, COUNT(*) AS Quantita 
  FROM prenotazioni 
  WHERE Cancellata IS NULL 
  AND FKCampo = 1 
  AND YEAR(Data) = YEAR(CURDATE()) -1 
  GROUP BY Mese 
) AS tmp RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS `number`
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
    UNION SELECT 6
    UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 9
    UNION SELECT 10
    UNION SELECT 11
    UNION SELECT 12
) AS `months` ON `months`.`number` = tmp.Mese
ORDER BY `months`.`number` ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to construct or find a table that has all the months you want and use a `LEFT JOIN`.

In your case, though, conditional aggregation might do this with a simpler query.  This assumes that you have at least one row for each month, even if that is filtered out by the existing `where` clause.

So, this might work:

```
SELECT MONTH(Data) AS Mese,
       SUM(Cancellata IS NULL AND FKCampo = 1 ) AS Quantita 
FROM prenotazioni 
WHERE YEAR(Data) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 
GROUP BY Mese 
ORDER BY Mese ASC ;
```

Of course, if the original table does not have all the months, then they still won't be in the result set and you are back to having to use an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea of @urban but simplifying the query using left join:

```
create table prenotazioni
    (
        id int auto_increment,
        Cancellata int  default null null,
        FKCampo    int  default 1    null,
        Data       date default null null,
        constraint table_nametes_pk
            primary key (id)
    );

    insert into prenotazioni (Cancellata, FKCampo, Data)
    values (null, 1, "2019-04-01"),
           (null, 1, "2019-04-01"),
           (null, 1, "2019-05-01"),
           (null, 1, "2019-05-01"),
           (null, 1, "2019-05-01"),
           (null, 1, "2019-01-01"),
           (null, 1, "2019-01-01"),
           (null, 1, "2020-01-01"),
           (null, 1, "2018-01-01");

    CREATE TABLE all_months (
     month_num INT
    );

    INSERT INTO all_months VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);

    select month_num, count(p.Data)
    from
        all_months am left join prenotazioni p on (am.month_num = month(p.Data))
    where
        p.id is null
       or
      (Cancellata IS NULL AND FKCampo = 1 AND YEAR(Data) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1)
    GROUP BY am.month_num
    ORDER BY am.month_num;
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Providing expected input and output would be more helpfull than downvoting someone that spent time trying to help you.